# Rover uncontrollable in low gravity

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've built a rover with the new rover wheels. It works great on Kerbin, but when I bring it to a low-gravity world like Minmus it is uncontrollable. When I accelerate, the back goes up. When I try to decelerate, the front goes up. Driving properly is practically impossible. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is that the default rover control keys (AWSD) are also mapped to vehicle rotation. You don't notice on Kerbin because the rotation power of command pods is too weak to overcome the gravity, but on low-gravity moons the effect becomes much more notable.

There are, however, two ways, to solve this problem.

**Method A:**
Go to the Settings menu and map the rover controls to other keys (many players use IJKL, because that's the keys used by most of the 3rd party Rover mods which existed before 0.19)

**Method B:**
Switch into docking mode, where the AWSD keys control lateral movement, which is only available when you have RCS thrusters on.