# Why won't my rover drive on Duna?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I just landed my first rover on Duna, but it doesn't want to drive around!  This same design zips around Kerbin like a tiny science race car, but just slowly slides down the very gentle hill it's parked on now that it's actually arrived at its destination.

I have plenty of power in the batteries and solar panels to keep them topped up.  None of the wheels are damaged (the alt-menu boxes all say status nominal).  I've got a probe core to operate the thing, and I can see the steering actuate when I tap on the keys.  I've made sure the brakes are off, since I've been fiddling with them to keep still to save the game (you can't save while moving).

I tried the stuff in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109621/rover-uncontrollable-in-low-gravity) with no success either.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug!  Somehow the wheel motors got disabled.  By going around to all of them and clicking disable and then enabling them again, it seems to have cleared out whatever bad state was in there.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have full probe control and set rover controls from `wasd` to `ijkl`.